# ansible inventory_hostname in module

Tags: python, ansible

I am writing a custom module, and I need to use `inventory_hostname` from playbook as variable for my module. I looked into `module.params` for `host` but I get `null` 
I am using `connection: network_cli` as I am working with network device.

Answer (score 0):

For reference: hostname is stored in `AnsibleModule` and can be retrieved with  `module.params.get('hostname')`