# How to find AnsibleModule and Params class documentation of member functions

Tags: ansible, documentation

I've found through various example code how to access params of an AnsibleModule using a member function `get()` (see below).

However I can't seem to find where it's documented. My IDE also can't follow the class definitions properly for it so I'm confused on how it works or where it's defined or what `get()` is a member function of.

**Here is the documentation and definition:**

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/module_utils.html#ansiblemodule
- https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/basic.py

**Some examples of usage:**

- https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/4b743a2721d9b89eab737b9e18510b5f4fa29214/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/vultr/vultr_firewall_rule.py#L373

  ```
  module = AnsibleModule(
      argument_spec=argument_spec,
      supports_check_mode=True,
  )

  if module.params.get('state') == "absent":
  ```

- https://blog.networktocode.com/post/how-to-write-an-ansible-module-part-1/

  - `want_contact = module.params.get('contact')`
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/60455421/13384507

  - "can be retrieved with `module.params.get('hostname')`"

I assume `module.params` is a Python dictionary in this case (thus there is a .get() member function). However this doesn't seem to be clear in documentation. What can I try next?

Comment: Please ask these questions separately as multiple questions in one post is not welcome.

Comment: @DischordDynne I've refined the question.

Comment: [developing modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html). What in that documentation makes you think `module.params` is anything but a dict?